# Discord.js guildMemberAdd event not called when join

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm trying to send a message when a user join to server, so I'm using `guildMemberAdd` event to handle it but for some reason it doesn't work. even if I send `console.log()` here is the code:

```js
const {Client, Attachment, RichEmbed, Collection} = require('discord.js');
const newUsers = new Collection()
const bot = new Client();
require('dotenv').config()


bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
console.log('new join');
    newUsers.set(member.id, member.user);
    channel.send('new user')
});
bot.on("guildMemberRemove", (member) => {
    console.log('remove')
    if(newUsers.has(member.id)) newUsers.delete(member.id);
  });

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Connected as ${bot.user.tag}`)
    bot.user.setActivity("Youtube",{type:"WATCHING"})

})

bot.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

I'm testing to join from Windows Software and from Browser but nothing, of course not with the bot user.
So, how does this event works?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the logs associated with the the user join action?

Comment: Where is it?  Settings->Audit Log?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't call the event because the user was already registered on server. I mean if someone join to server for the first time, the event will be called.